# Using PUT and DELETE methods via HiddenHttpMethodFilter causes error 405

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm new in Spring and I'm trying to make my Spring MVC application process PUT and DELETE requests. I've read in Reference Documentation that `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` is used for this purpose.

Here is a part of my `web.xml` with filters:

```
<filter> 
<filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name> 
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class> 
</filter> 

<filter-mapping> 
<filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name> 
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping> 

<filter> 
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> 
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy 
</filter-class> 
</filter> 

<filter-mapping> 
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> 
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

I'll show only `PUT` request sending (for `DELETE` it's the very same thing).

I'm sending request from the following form (using `<form:/>` Spring namespace that implicitly sets `_method` field):

```
<form:form name="editableForm" commandName="blogRecord" action="${update_url}" method="put">
```

and the controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/update")  
public ModelAndView update(@ModelAttribute("entity") @Valid Entity entity) { 
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView(); 
    service.update(entity); 
    model.setViewName("/blog/success"); 
    model.addObject("record", entity); 
    return model; 
}
```

As I see in debugger, `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` is actually executed, and controller method successfully performs update and returns `200`, but then somewhere in `DispatcherServlet` or `FrameworkServlet` it returns the following error:

```
HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'PUT' not supported
```

what can be the cause of such a strange behavior? Thanks in advance =)

Comment: Double check the csrf token

Comment: Could you post your network tracking?

Comment: @Hitham S. AlQadheeb, how can I avoid it?

Comment: @chaoluo, response code 200 is invisible in `Network` tab, I can see it only while debug. 
https://snag.gy/RaFusd.jpg